# Commands are no longer displayed since they are in the cog

Tags: discord.py

I use discord.py

My commands are no longer displayed since they are in the cog.

Code starts

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Wuensche(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(name="goodnight", description="Wünsche allen eine gute Nacht")
    async def goodnight(self, interaction: discord.interactions.Interaction):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Gute Nacht!",
                                 description=f"{interaction.user.mention} wünscht allen eine gute Nacht.",
                                 color=0x000000)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embedVar)

    @commands.Cog.slash_command(name="goodmorning", description="Wünsche allen einen schönen Morgen.")
    async def goodmorning(self, interaction: discord.interactions.Interaction):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Guten Morgen!",
                                 description=f"{interaction.user.mention} wünscht allen einen guten Morgen.",
                                 color=0xFFFF00)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embedVar)

    @commands.Cog.slash_command(name="goodmidday", description="Wünsche allen einen guten Mittag.")
    async def goodmidday(self, interaction: discord.interactions.Interaction):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Guten Mittag",
                                 description=f"{interaction.user.mention} wünscht allen einen guten Mttag.",
                                 color=0x1a4646)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embedVar)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_Cog(Wuensche(bot))

for filename in os.listdir("cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
        print('[✅]Loaded')
```

Code ends

This is in the run register:
C:\Users\Yasha\PycharmProjects\BotFürFox\main.py:94: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited
bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: You never call `setup`, and even if you did, `add_Cog` is incorrectly capitalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 2.0.0 the `setup` function is asynchronous:

```py
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Wuensche(bot))
```

You also don't need to load again the extensions in the cog...